# How To Check Response.statusCode in sendSynchronousRequest on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

How To check response.statusCode in SendSynchronousRequest in Swift
The Code is Below :

```
let urlPath: String = "URL_IS_HERE"
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)
var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
var response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?> = nil

var error: NSErrorPointer? = nil
var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: response, error: nil) as NSData?
```

before and in objective c , we check response.statusCode With this :
      (long)response.statusCode
but in swift i have no idea how can check response status Code

Answer (score 116, accepted):

you pass in a reference to response so it is filled THEN you check the result and cast it to a HTTPResponse as only http responses declare the status code property.

```
let urlPath: String = "http://www.google.de"
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)
var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
var response: NSURLResponse?

var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: nil) as NSData?

if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
    println("error \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
}
```

*note: in objC you would also use the same approach but if you use squared brackets, the compiler doesn't enforce the cast. Swift (being type safe) does enforce the cast always*

Comment: You can combine/simplify the `if` and `let` statements to `if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse { ... }`.

Comment: yip right Im not that used to the if let construct but it is cleaner! -- edited

Comment: All types in your answer that begin with NS have now dropped the NS.
NSHTTPURLResponse -> HTTPURLResponse
This is a note for future programmers.

Answer (score 85):

Swift 3 version for @GarySabo answer:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://apple.com")!
let request = URLRequest(url: url)

let task = URLSession.shared().dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in

    if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        print("statusCode: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
    }

}
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 18):

I use an extension to URLResponse to simplify this one (Swift 3):

```
extension URLResponse {

    func getStatusCode() -> Int? {
        if let httpResponse = self as? HTTPURLResponse {
            return httpResponse.statusCode
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: And how do you use it? An example would have been nice

Comment: usage: `if let statusCode = urlResponse.getStatusCode() { /*...*/ }`

Answer (score 18):

**Swift 3+**

```
let dataURL = "https://myurl.com"
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: dataURL)!)
        request.addValue("Bearer \(myToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            // Check if the response has an error
            if error != nil{
                print("Error \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse{
                if httpResponse.statusCode == 401{
                    print("Refresh token...")
                    return
                }
            }

            // Get data success

        }.resume()
```

Answer (score 13):

Create extension to check valid/invalid response -

```
extension HTTPURLResponse {
     func isResponseOK() -> Bool {
      return (200...299).contains(self.statusCode)
     }
}
```

Get response from request -

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (jsonData, response, error) in

                // post result on main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.isResponseOK() {
                        // assume if we don't receive any error then its successful
                        handler(true)
                    } else {
                        handler(false)
                    }
                }

            }
            task.resume()
        }
```

Answer (score 11):

Cleaned up for Swift 2.0 using NSURLSession

```
let urlPath: String = "http://www.google.de"
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
var response: NSURLResponse?


let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {urlData, response, reponseError in

         if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
             print("error \(httpResponse.statusCode)")  
          }

 }
 task.resume()
 //You should not write any code after `task.resume()`
```

Answer (score 7):

For Swift 5.5 with `await`

```
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
            print ("httpResponse.statusCode: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")

            throw(Error.invalidHttpResponseCode)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [Just](http://JustHTTP.net) library it'd be as simple as:

```
Just.get("URL_IS_HERE").statusCode
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.7**
You can try this on the playground:

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

let url = URL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com")!

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error ?? "Unknown error")
        return
    }
    if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        print("statusCode: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
    }
    let contents = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print(contents!)
}.resume()

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 5.5+, iOS 15.0+**

For Swift concurrency with async-await and handling a diverse set of success response status codes, consider the following implementation:

```
func sendRequest(_ request: URLRequest) async throws -> Data {
    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    guard let httpResponse = (response as? HTTPURLResponse),
            200...299 ~= httpResponse.statusCode else {
        throw NetworkError.failResponse
    }
    return data
}
```

This function efficiently handles asynchronous requests, ensuring that the response falls within the successful status code range.